# Use of console.time

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm creating an application with Google Closure Library and its Compiler. To debug values I use `console.log()`. Compiling this will throw the following exception `JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable console is undeclared at ...`. To solve this error, I just had to use `window.console.log()` instead.
I also want to measure the time that a function takes. Firebug has two nice functions `console.time(name)` and `console.timeEnd(name)` to do that very easily. Unfortunately the Closure Compiler does not support these functions throwing the following warning `JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY. Property time never defined on Window.prototype.console at ...`. Unfortunately you cannot solve this warning with prepending `window`.
I also had a look at the library, but goog.debug.Console has not the function that I need.
Another solution I have used before was something like the following

```
var start = new Date();  
// do something
var end = new Date();

// do some calculation to get the ms for both start and end
var startMS = ....;
var endMS = .....;
// get the difference and print it
var difference = (endMS - startMS) / 1000;
console.log('Time taken for something: ' + difference);
```

This is a little bit too much code, if you use it very often, and the version with the two functions would be great:

```
window.console.time("timeTaken");
// do something
window.console.timeEnd("timeTaken");
```

This prints out the MS between start and end. But as mentioned above, this doesn't work with the closure compiler. Does anyone have a solution for this, how I can use these two functions `window.console.time()` and `window.console.timeEnd()`? Or maybe another solution that goog.closure provides, but I haven't found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to added them to the externs you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. While trying to declare the firebug extension and having a lot of errors (Firebug uses the CONST keyword, that is not allowed with the Closure Compiler), I found in the directory of the Compiler the _webkit_console.js_, in which both functions are declared.

Comment: yeah, "const" isn't part of the standard thus isn't supported. We have to wait for EcmaScript 6 for that. Personally, I can't wait. "/** @const */" isn't nearly as likely to be used.

Comment: We did add a "--accept_const_keyword" option to make things simpler for people, this simply rewrites "const" as "var" for the rest of the compiler.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Closure - could you give an example of the extern declaration for `console`?

Comment: minimally:

var console;
console.time; 
console.timeEnd;

You can use the existing externs as to get a general feel of things: https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/externs/es3.js

Comment: https://code.google.com/searchframe#l5BkQmivP-Y/trunk/contrib/externs/webkit_console.js

Comment: Both links above are dead, any other sources?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to/can't use externs, you can easily reference "undeclared" objects with the string-based properties:

```
window['console']['log']('Hello Console!');
window['console']['time']('timeTaken');
...
```

But you have to be careful, because the second line might throw an error if the `time` property does not exist or it's not a function.